# jsTree How to activate a parent node and show contents at right side

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have three parent node of jsTree, by default the first parent node is selected and the contents at right side are showing, I want jquery code to select(active) second/third parent node and show its contents , the select_node work only to highlight and select node with id specified, but it doesn't actually activate the node to show its contents. I have tried open_node which expands the selected node and show child. can anyone help me. 
the code I tried for select and open:

```
$('#jstree_div').jstree('select_node', '#j1_8_anchor', function(e, data) {
 // code logic....this code only select the node with id j1_8_anchor
}, true);

$('#jstree_div').jstree('open_node', '#j1_8_anchor', function(e, data) {
 // code logic....this code only open (expand) the node with id j1_8_anchor
}, true);

$('#j1_8_anchor').click();//doesn't work to activate node 
$('#j1_8_anchor').dblclick();//doesn't work to activate node
```

Comment: Do you want to expand all nodes under a certain parent node?

Comment: @NikolayErmakov No I want to select a parent node and then open the child node under this, because when the parent node is not selected then child can't be opened this is the real issue . suppose I have two parent nodes A and B, now by default A is selected then we can open A-1, A-2 child nodes of A. But we cant open B-2 a child node of B, because B isn't selected. What I need to redirect user from other page and select B-1 node and open the contents of it.

Comment: And `open_node` doesn't work for you?

Comment: no, open_node doesn't open it only expands the node.

Comment: Maybe you could attach a screen shot to illustrate your problem, or better create a Fiddle demo.